# Undefined symbols for architecture i386: "_AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID"

Tags: xcode, xcode4

I am trying to make a soundboard app and i get this error

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
      "_AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID", referenced from:
          -[S0undFXViewController sound1] in S0undFXViewController.o
          -[S0undFXViewController sound2] in S0undFXViewController.o
          -[S0undFXViewController sound3] in S0undFXViewController.o
          -[S0undFXViewController sound4] in S0undFXViewController.o
          -[S0undFXViewController sound5] in S0undFXViewController.o
          -[S0undFXViewController sound6] in S0undFXViewController.o
```

Comment: A little more context would help us understand your situation. What are you trying to do? What is your code? What libraries are you using?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That sort of error is usually caused by a missing framework.

Have you added the AudioServices framework to your project? It isn't enough to just import the header files.

**Edit**

Actually, if you turn on module support in Xcode, it is enough to just @import the Framework.